# Event handler click instead of select

Tags: javascript

I have an ionic select with a list of users, 
In this list I have an option that will redirect me to another page:
in my list I have an item that will act like a button at the moment it will select it and redirect me, I only want it to act like a button and don't be selected

> My list:

[image]

Is there a way to handle this please ?

```
  <ion-select interface="popover" [ngModel]="selecteduser._id" (ngModelChange)="selectUser($event)" (ionChange)="onChange($event)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user._id">
      </ion-content>{{ getUserNickname(user }} </ion-option>
    <ion-option>Go To Modal</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

So I want when I click on my Go To Modal, it will redirect me to my modal.
without selecting it.

There is my ts

```
  onChange(value: any) {
    if (value === 'Go To Modal') {
      this.openConfig()
    }
  }

  openConfig() {
    this.modalCtrl.create(configModal).present()
    console.log('heeey')
  }

  selectUser(userId: string) {
    this.selectedUser = this.users.find(b => b._id === userId)
    this.onSelect.emit(this.selectedUser)
  }
```

Comment: If I understood right you need to disable default behavior of select and write logic of it manually

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr Yes Sir, only for my two last Item.

Comment: So you should prevent  default  behavior  of select and handle  changes manually

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr Could you please tell me how to do it ? i'm stuck